# 'Yes to all' or 'No to any' with multiple individual questions - The best way to present to the user

Tags: forms, gui-design, web, guidelines

I have list of approximately eight questions that need to be answered on a form (yes/no). If the answer to *any* of these questions is 'no' then the user is taken to page x, while if the answer to *all* questions in 'yes' then they are taken to page y.

To my mind, the interface for this could be done in two ways:

1. A checkbox (or radio buttons) for each of the eight questions with a submit button at the bottom. The user can then individually asses each question, select the checkbox as required and then submit their answers.
2. List each of the questions in a list format (or similar) with a statement like 'Do all of the above apply?', followed by a 'yes' and 'no' button.

It seems like the second option will be the simplest option and require the least effort to complete, but I am wondering if the first option would lead to a more accurate overall result as it forces the user to consider and register an answer for each question individually - e.g. less like to skip over questions etc, especially on repeat uses.

Is there a generally held rule to how something like this should be presented?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should force the user to check each question. The time-consuming nature of the form is a feature rather than bulk, because it is important the user answers each individual question accurately.

A button idea is less intuitive than it looks like. When your form is read sequentially, the user is implicitly asked to remember all of his answer in order to click correctly : this probably won't happen, and he will be forced to read again once he hits the button at the bottom of the page.

A third way to present this could be to present question one by one with yes and no buttons each directing to the next question. The user could be skipped to "x" page as soon as he answers "no" to an item, saving him the cost of reading unnecessary questions.

Comment: Thanks Arthur, I think you're right. I will go with a slightly modified version of your third option, which I had considered also.

Comment: Agreed, forcing users to remember stuff is adding to their cognitive load.

Answer (score 2):

We work with similar questions on .GOV and my feeling is to test each scenario:

A set of 8 checkboxes. IF 8 checked then goto X ELSE goto Y.

A set of 8 statements with a pre condition saying "do **all** of these apply?"

My feelings is the second option will increase cognitive load and lead to some things not being read while the first option would allow you go guide the user to the correct place with extra data of what was clicked or not clicked.

But you can test both to be absolutely sure. In GDS assessments we have to show we test variations to be absolutely sure about things